# how to correctly disable power management in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, petalinux

I am trying to disable power management in Linux for Zynq Ultrascale devices. Looking at the kernel, it is enabled by default. When I set `CONFIG_PM=n` and build the kernel, it doesn't take effect. Also I wish to know if there is any dependency on other mdoules like `CONFIG_SUSPEND` ?

I tried disabling both of the above parameters by setting `CONFIG_PM=n` and `CONFIG_SUSPEND=n` in my kernel.cfg. But it throws out a big blob of error which is very difficult for me as a entry level embedded linux engineer to understand. Can someone shine some light on this.

**Edit:**

Based on the suggestion from @sawdust. I tried to do the kernel changes using menuconfig. Then the petalinux-build breaks. I am a newbie and it is a bit difficult to understand from the log, why it breaks.

Will be great to have some experienced eyes look over the build log and suggest why it fails.

https://gist.github.com/cody70b/b866dce72ae7080981edbc2ffbc4f8e9

Comment: "*When I set `CONFIG_PM=n` ...*" -- Since that's an incorrect value for disabling a kernel configuration selection, you would be better off using the tried and true method of using the `make menuconfig` command. You should heed the warning at the top of the **.config** file!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will proceed with menuconfig. Also, is there a way to verify/check on the generated image, if the power management feature is disabled or not ?

Comment: There are a few different ways in your case on how to check. One of them is to enable configuration to be compiled in the kernel and `grep COMFIG_PM /proc/config` (or something like that) will show you the result.